# UIGestureRecognizer over UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, swipe

I need to detect left and right swipe over a UIScrollView with 3 fingers when horizontal scrolling is possible. I need to keep all the interactions with 1 and 2 fingers. Is it possible to do that without rewrite all gesture recognision.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's possible. Add a swipe gesture to your UIScrollView and be sure to implement

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

So they will not cancel each other.